# How to get a video preview on search engine with VideoJS?

Tags: video, seo, search-engine, video.js

I had some problems with [my video blog](http://vid.technologeek.net/). The preview of my video on Google is the default preview of videos. Even if the video last 1:20, Google shows that it lasts 0:20.
Is it possible to modify it ?
Best regards, Brunner Nathan

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to modify it ?

yes if you are using a [Google video sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80472), just make sure that the correct video duration is specified in that. So for your example it would be `<video:duration>80</video:duration>`